# Casting MKAnnotationView fails in IOS 6

Tags: iphone, ios, cocoa-touch, ios6

I'm subclassing a MKAnnotationView to change the default annotation image with something else. This worked fine in IOS4, but now that I try to compile and run it for IOS6 I get the following error message:

[MKPinAnnotationView setImageForAnnotationWithType:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x25936400

The setImageForAnnotationWithType is of course defined. To me it seems like it is unable to cast the annotationView object correctly.

I get the annotation object using this line:

```
LAnnotationView *anotationView = [_mapView viewForAnnotation:anotation];
```

This line calls the following method where I cast and return the object:

```
-  (LAnnotationView *) viewForAnnotation:(Annotation *)annotation
{
    LAnnotationView *resultView = (LAnnotationView *) [_mapView viewForAnnotation:annotation];
    return resultView;
}
```

After returning the object I call the actual method that fails:

```
[anotationView setImageForAnnotationWithType:LMapAnnotationGreenArrow];
```

I've tried to use isKindOfClass to check the class type, and it also fails. Any clue what could be wrong here?
As mentioned it worked fine in previous version of IOS.

Comment: This question is not related neither to Xcode nor to Cocoa. Removed those tags and added 'cocoa-touch'. By the way, casting won't make one object magically become another (as C itself is weakly typed and Objective-C has duck typing).

Comment: Show how the viewForAnnotation delegate method is implemented.  It seems to be returning an MKPinAnnotationView instead of your custom view.  By the way, isn't the first line calling viewForAnnotation directly on the map view instead of your "cast" method?

Comment: Yes you might be into something here. The viewForAnnotation returns an object of MKPinAnnotationView. Further debugging could indicate that it is the routine where I add the new pin that is the problem, because the map is showing a regular pin instead of my custom one on startup. I might be looking in the wrong place here.